# Python regular expression unable to find pattern - using pyspark on Apache Spark

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark

Can someone let me why the regular expression

```
df = df2.withColumn("extracted", F.regexp_extract("title", "[Pp]ython", 0))
```

Can find the pattern 'Python' or 'python' from the followng column called title

```
title
A fast PostgreSQL client library for Python: 3x faster than psycopg2
A project template for data science in Python
A simple python framework to build/train LUIS models
An Introduction to Stock Market Data Analysis with Python (Part 1)
Asynchronous Python
Cubr  A Rubiks Cube Solver Written in Python and using Webcam Input (2013)
Python 4 Kids: Python for Kids: Python 3  Project 10
```

But the regular expression can't find the pattern Python or python from the following

```
title
Python Core Development Sprint 2016: 3.6 and beyond
Hypothesis.works articles: 3.5.0 and 3.5.1 Releases of Hypothesis for Python
Total pip packages downloaded, separated by Python versions (June  August 2016)
PEP 530: Asynchronous Comprehensions in Python 3.6
Python 2.7 still reigns supreme in pip installs
CheckiO  games for Python and JavaScript coders. ClassRoom support is included
VR Zero, Virtual Reality on the RaspberryPi, in Python
```

Thanks

Comment: Any error messages? What output do you get?

Comment: Hi, I don't get any error messages, the pattern is simply not found. When I run the equivalent code in SQL %ython% all the patterns are found. Very strange

Comment: If you were to run the same PySpark regular  expression you would see what I mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the ignore case regex;

`(?i)`-ignore or case-insensitive mode ON

Data

data=[

```
  (1,"Python Core Development Sprint 2016: 3.6 and beyond"),
  (2,"Hypothesis.works articles: 3.5.0 and 3.5.1 Releases of Hypothesis for Python"),
  (3,"CheckiO  games for python and JavaScript coders. ClassRoom support is included")
  ]
df=spark.createDataFrame(data, ['id','title'])
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Solution

```
df.withColumn('extract', F.regexp_extract(col('title'),'(?i)[P]ython',0)).show()
```

Outcome

```
+---+--------------------+-------+
| id|               title|extract|
+---+--------------------+-------+
|  1|Python Core Devel...| Python|
|  2|Hypothesis.works ...| Python|
|  3|CheckiO  games fo...| python|
+---+--------------------+-------+
```